# After adding new cell, how to get the UITableViewControler to save the new entry, so when app is closed and re opened the new cell is there

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Ok, so I'm new to iOS Development. I have just created a master view application for note taking. Every thing works fine except for one thing, after a new cell is created and i stop the app and reopen the app the new cell is not there!

Thanks in advance!

Master View Controller.m

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"

#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController
@synthesize myTableView, numbers;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //NSMT arry
    numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four", nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

}
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];

    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alert show];

    /*
     if (!numbers) {
     numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     }
     [numbers insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
     [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
     */
}
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [myTableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}
#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return numbers.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [numbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [numbers removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    //if user hits OK
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSString * tempTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
        if (!numbers) {
            numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        [numbers insertObject:tempTextField atIndex:0];

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [self.myTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }

}
/*
 // Override to support rearranging the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
 {
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
 return YES;
 }
 */

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}

@end
```

MasterViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * numbers;


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps tell us how you're storing the data used to populate the tableview. As this is what you need to save.

You could save it using CoreData or just use NSUserDefaults, there are plenty of options open to you. However, without knowing how you data is currently structured it's hard to give you a specific example.

Show some code and you'll get a better answer.